# Understanding HTML font-size differences in iphone and android

Tags: android, iphone, html, css

I'm trying to present a simple message to the user in my mobile website.
I want the message size approximately will be the same on mobile devices with similar screen size, for example iPhone and Samsung Galaxy (android).

I read a lot of posts on this issue, and many recommended to use `-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%` to make it happen. But I didn't understand how to use it...

The webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html { -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align:center;font-size:6em;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;">
        Hello World!
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you test the viewports meta?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, height=device-height"/>
```